# How can I write a contraint in gurobi that involves min of a set?

Tags: python, gurobi

I am having trouble with this constraint:

E_i1,...,i <= min{x1,...,xi} where i comes from a set of 9 numbers called I. x and E are variables and binary.

I tried:

```
for i in I:

    f = model.addConstr(E[i] <= min((x[i])) , name = "f")

    print(x[i])

    print(E[I])
```

but it was giving the value of zero to all the E since it would just evaluate all the x.

The objective function should be:

(ΣPijk * xi) - Σ(pi1jk * ... * pi) * Ei

which means that it should evaluate the first P with the second P and the value of E will be based on the value of x of those two. Ex:
P1jk*1 + P2jk*1 + P3jk*0 - ((P1jk*P2jk)*(1)) - ((P2jk*P3jk)*(0))

So for the first (P1jk*P2jk)(1), E=1 because the min between {x1,x2} is 1.

For the second (P2jk*P3jk)(0), E=0 because the min between {x2,x3} is 0

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is very hard to understand. Please try to formulate it more clearly. You seem to only constrain every E[i] to be less-equal than a single x[i]. There is no set in the constraint.

Comment: Check out this part in the documentation: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/constraints.html#subsubsection:GeneralConstraints